# Concurrent read/write buffer byte[] in java

Tags: java, multithreading, buffer, byte

I'm new to Java and I want to implement a buffer of `byte[]` which one thread can write into, and another thread can read from.
It sounds like it should have already been implemented in `java`, but I spent hours trying to find/understand several number of classes, and I didn't understand if it does what I want, and how to use it.
I saw `BufferedInputStream`, `ByteBuffer`, `ByteChannel`, `BlockingQueue`...

Can someone please point to a more specific direction?
I use `SDK 1.6`

Comment: Are reads/writes always sequential? Is the byte array a fixed size? And no, I don't believe Java has such a class builtin, you'll have to write it yourself and synchronize it appropriately (note: by "sequential" here, I mean "not random", ie you don't read from the middle of the array/write into the middle of the array)

Comment: The byte array isn't a fixed size. reader and writer doesn't have to be sequential...

Comment: Then a custom class it is for you...

Comment: @fge, Sorry, I just saw your edit. It is sequential. (a reader reads the first block of bytes available in queue, a writer writes to the end of the queue)

Comment: Even then you'll need a custom class. It'd be more simple if reads/writes were of fixed size but it would be too simple, wouldn't it? ;)

Comment: What about a simple pipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, `ByteBuffer` wasn't good for me cause it involves playing with the `position` of the buffer.
I realized all I really needed was a simple `pipe` (I don't know how could I forget about pipes).

I used an example from [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/pipes.html):

```
PipedOutputStream output = new PipedOutputStream();
PipedInputStream input = new PipedInputStream(output);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking to simply stream bytes from one thread to the other, I suggest you use `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream`. Though note that it's likely you're in this position where you need a solution such as this because of a design fault.

Here is how you would do such thing, for instance:

```
PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream();
PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream(out);
new YourReadingThread(in).start();
new YourWritingThread(out).start();
```

Then anything you write to `out` will be available for reading through `in`.

---

If you're looking for a solution to make a thread safe ByteBuffer, I would suggest you use a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`:

```
ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(n);

// Reading thread:
lock.readLock().lock();
buffer.get(i);
lock.readLock().unlock();

// Writing thread:
lock.writeLock().lock();
buffer.put(b,i);
lock.writeLock().unlock();
```